# Django many2many is a subset of another set

Tags: python, django, m2m, database-optimization

Given a model with an m2m field, let's say `Article` has multiple `Authors`.
What is the most efficient way to get all the articles in which the set of their authors is a subset of another set?

```
class Article(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('Author')
```

Get all articles that were written by one or many of the authors in this list but doesn't have any author that is not part of this list.

```
authors_list = ['Tom', 'John', 'Sara', 'Kati']
```

- Articles written by 'Tom' would match.
- Articles written by 'Tom' and 'Sara' would match.
- But, Articles written by 'Tom' and 'Alter' would NOT match.

Comment: What does your `Author` model look like? What approaches have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about your author model, this is just a guess, but this general approach should work:

```
authors = Author.objects.filter(first_name__in=authors_list)
others = Author.objects.exclude(first_name__in=authors_list)
queryset = Article.objects.filter(authors__in=authors)
queryset = queryset.exclude(authors__in=others)
```